# How does one pass a prop as null in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

i have a conundrum.

I have text I want toggling in a component.

basically `true` => `tick` and `false` => `untick`
but i want a 3rd scenario where I don't want any text displayed

if I don't pass the prop to that component, it is automatically assuming true. can I pass propName={null} or something like that?

or will i have to extract this into a function (i'd much rather not)

Comment: *"if I don't pass the prop to that component, it is automatically assuming true"* wait, what? can you show the component. I'd assume it to resolve as `falsy`, if anything.

Comment: @Thomas yes I agree that is to be expected when I removed the prop. the text returned with true was returned

Answer (score 2):

If you do not provide the prop to the component it will not be present in the object representing props within that component. You could therefore check whether or not the prop is defined:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  if (props.checked === undefined) {
     return <Something />;
  }

  return <SomethingElse someProp={props.checked} />;
};
```

Then, this will render `Something`:

```
<Component />
```

And these will all render `SomethingElse`:

```
<Component checked />
<Component checked={true} />
<Component checked={false} />
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me solve it. I ended up writing a function and then passing null to the function when I didn't want text

Answer (score 0):

You can have a third state `null` but then you will need to do explicit comparisons i.e `a == false` and don't evaluate `a` as it will become false in case of null as well